# HTML Registration Form - Array not treated as empty()

Tags: php, html, forms

Heyo newbie to PHP here,

I'm creating a registration form where the user is able to select how many family members are in the family, Depending on the number selected the same number of fields would be created to allow them to enter family members' details.

The form checks if all error messages are empty before starting the database insert.

I've been trying for hours though still not sure what's causing the array to return empty() - False,

**Full Code - 
[GDrive Share Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ww7SzrrLtv8ciN-VLaoGR-B2OMmhtpBp)**

Creation of the Arrays

```
$MemberNameErr = array();
$MemberDOBErr = array();
```

Giving the Array values based on the number of Family Members

```
for($Variable_Counter = 0; $Variable_Counter < $Family_Counter; 
$Variable_Counter++)
{
 $MemberNameErr[$Variable_Counter] = "";
 $MemberDOBErr[$Variable_Counter] = "";
}
```

If function that checks that no errors have been made

```
if ($FamilyNameErr == "" && $DateErr == "" && $EmailErr == "" && $PhoneErr == "" && $MobileErr == "" && empty($MemberNameErr) && empty($MemberDOBErr)) 
{
```

currently using empty() as a way to check if the array is empty

created these just to check if the arrays were Not Empty

```
if (!empty($MemberNameErr))
{
  echo " MEMBER ERROR NOT EMPTY ";  
}
if (!empty($MemberDOBErr))
{
    echo " DOB ERROR NOT EMPTY ";  
}
```

Thank you for all your input.

Comment: I'm not sure the array would actually be empty if you are populating it with that for loop, even if all the values are empty. Is there a reason you need an index for each iteration of the array if they might be null anyway? What if instead of pushing a blank string to each index you only inserted something when there was actually an error?

Comment: @tshimkus As they are used to display an error when filling the form, leaving them empty causes errors within the form, As the variable has not been initialized but has been called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop

```
for($Variable_Counter = 0; $Variable_Counter < $Family_Counter; $Variable_Counter++)
{
    $MemberNameErr[$Variable_Counter] = "";
    $MemberDOBErr[$Variable_Counter] = "";
}
```

You're assigning empty string to indexes of the array. This means the array isn't empty anymore.

In example :

```
$tab = array("", "", "");
if (empty($tab))
{
    echo "Empty";
}
else
{
    echo "Not empty";
}
```

**Output :**

> Not empty

A workaround could be to iterate through this array and check if there's at least 1 non empty string.

In example

```
function CheckNonEmptyValue($arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $value)
    {
        if (!empty($value))
        {
            return (true);
        }
    }
    return (false);
}

if (CheckNonEmptyValue($MemberNameErr))
{
    echo " MEMBER ERROR NOT EMPTY ";
}

if (CheckNonEmptyValue($MemberDOBErr))
{
    echo " DOB ERROR NOT EMPTY ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Cid

I was led to believe that empty strings are considered empty through this page.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

I need to initialize empty strings as they are used as error messages, leaving them null causes errors.

Comment: Empty strings **are** considered as empty, but an array containing only empty string **is not** empty.

Comment: Alright that really clears things up then, Thank you very much Cid,

Comment: That's like having many match boxes that are empty and a chest that is empty too. You put all your empty boxes in the chest and your chest isn't empty anymore (even if the boxes are empty)